# Filter in a column and copying data from another column

Tags: excel, vba

I have below code where it filter 1 in AT column from worksheet1 and try to copy data in AS,E,C columns and paste in worksheet2. Problem is, it is not able to copy entire data in E and C if there are blanks in the middle as end(xldown) is only able to copy until first blank cell. Can someone help me to correct it so that once 1 is filtered in column AT then code should be able to copy data in columns E and C from start to end.

```
        Worksheets(worksheet1).select
Rows("3:3").select
Selection.autofilter
Range(AT).slect
Activehseet.Range("$A$3:$AT$1185").Autofilter Field:=46, Criteria:="1"
Range("AS4").Select
Range(Selction, Selection.End(xldown)).select
Selection.copy
```

- same as above to copy data in E and C columns

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is absolutely necessary [to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in order to produce reliable code.

Second issue is that as you found out `Selection.End(xlDown)` will go down until the next free cell. In order to find the very last used cell in a column you need to start from the very last cell and go `xlUp`:

```
Set LastUsedCell = Cells(Rows.Count, "AS").End(xlUp)
```

So to get rid of all `.Select` and `Selection` statements first declare a variable that works as a reference to your worksheet:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName")
```

Now you can access this worksheet using `ws` without needing to select it. Then you need to find the last used row in column AT. Otherwise your filter using `Range("$A$3:$AT$1185")` is limited to 1185.

```
Dim LastUsedCell As Range
Set LastUsedCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "AS").End(xlUp)

ws.Range("$A$3", LastUsedCell).Autofilter Field:=46, Criteria:="1"
```

If you now want to copy only the filtered data you need to make sure that you get only the visible cells in your filtered range, because `ws.Range("$A$3", LastUsedCell)` will refer to all cells in that range not only the ones you filtered.

```
Dim FilteredData As Range
On Error Resume Next  'next line will throw an error if there are no visible cells
Set FilteredData = ws.Range("$A$4", LastUsedCell).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error Goto 0  'don't forget to re-enable error reporting!
```

Finally you need to test if visible cells were found:

```
If FilteredData Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No filtered data found"
    Exit Sub
End If

FilteredData.Copy
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Peh but can you also help me to pick data from AS and E ,C once we apply filter in AT. I think above filtereddata.copy copies all the data in the worksheet after the filter right!!

Comment: @SharmilaV Analog to the first column: `Set FilteredData = ws.Range("E4", "E" & LastUsedCell.Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`